# ASP.Net core C# MVC: Can Model function have parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core C#.

Can model contain of parameter and if else statement? 
I have a program allows the user to convert alpha to number or number to alpha. Can I do the comparison at the model to return data instead of controller?

Currently my method at model:

```
public class converter
{

    private string _code;
    private int _code2;

    public string AlphaToNumberic(String s)
    {
        if (s.Equals("ab")) { _code = "12"; }
        else if (s.Equals("cd")) { _code = "34"; }
        return _code;
    }

    public string NumbericToAlpha(String s)
    {
        if (s.Equals("12")) { _code = "ab"; }
        else if (s.Equals("34")) { _code = "cd"; }
        return _code;
    }
}


public string NumbericToAlphaV  
{
    set
    {
        _code = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return _code;
    }
}
```

However I never saw anyone did that before. Another way I thought of using this:

```
public string NumbericToAlphaV  
{
    set
    {
        _code = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return _code;
    }
}
```

but this way, if I try to add a parameter, will cause an error. What is the good practice in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question - yes, model **should** contain methods with parameters, if else statements and other necessary constructions.

Longer answer would be actually too long for SO format, because it involves some basic concepts of software design. I would recommend reading about [anemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) which basically is model as data structures, without any **behaviours**. Good model should concentrate on what modelled thing do instead of what attributes it has, as Martin Fowler says

> The catch comes when you look at the behavior, and you realize that there is hardly any behavior on these objects, making them little more than bags of getters and setters.